How to query the vector database in LangChain AgentExecutor, invoice before summarizing the 'Final Answer' after all tools have been called?
How to query the vector database in LangChain AgentExecutor, invoice before summarizing the 'Final Answer' after all tools have been called?
LangChain AgentExecutor code:
llm = ChatOpenAI()
tools = [tool_1, tool_2, ...]

prompt = hub.pull("hwchase17/openai-tools-agent")
my_agent = create_openai_tools_agent(llm, tools, prompt)
agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=my_agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)
question = "user's question"
ans = agent_executor.invoke({"input": question})

Querying Vector Database:
docs = vector_store.similarity_search(question)
new_question = f'''
Please answer my question based on my information

My information: ...

My question: ...
'''


Vector database call -> Put it inside a function. Use Pydantic for schema.
Then create a Tool() object using that function.
Pass that tool to agent while defining executor.
During execution, agent will pick the tool based on your tool description.

Thank you for your response! Encapsulating the vector database query into a Tool is indeed a good solution.
But I’d like to know if there are other ways to perform a vector database query before generating the Final Answer?
For example, querying the vector library once before generating the Final Answer, or other ways.

Yes. You can. It's how you design your code. You can retrieve the vectors in a separate function - totally separate from Agent code. Hold those vectors in a var. Then create another function to return those output vectors (metadata, description). And then use that function in a Tool() object and tell Agent to use it saying say - "Details about the retrieved vectors for the input".
